# how to combine SPI input with websocket in nodemcu python

Tags: embedded

nodemcu is a very common device ,and i am really struggling for a long time with sending over wifi input spi data with python.
I google many times this sort of combination and tryind to assemble the code.Is there a good manual which could show how exactly to broardcast over socket SPI data?
Thanks.

```
from machine import Pin,SPI
import network
import usocket as socket
ap_if = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
ssid = 'sensor_net'
password = '123456789'
ap_if.active(True)
ap_if.config(essid=ssid, password=password)
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('',80))
s.listen(5)
spi=SPI(1, baudrate=1000000, polarity=0, phase=0)
while True:
    spi.write(b'1234')
    conn, addre=s.accept()
    request='<p style="color:red"><u><h1>The temperature is:</u></p>'
    request2=str(12.7)
    response='gyhkjgku'
    conn.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n')
    conn.send('Content-type: text/html\n')
    conn.send('Connection: close\n\n')
    conn.sendall(request)
    conn.sendall(request2)
    conn.close()
    spi.write(b'1234')
```

Comment: Is your question about reading SPI or sending data over a socket, for the later, this would be a StackOverflow question.

Comment: both,i want to recieve data over SPI and send it to web socket ,
But SPI and web sockets dont play together good.So i wonder good because of the blobking situation.i tried to put nonblocking command in the socket code ,its not working.
So it would be great if anyone new a manual regarding recieving SPI and sending it over a socket.

Comment: both,i want to recieve data over SPI and send it to web socket ,
But SPI and web sockets dont play together good.So i wonder good because of the blobking situation.i tried to put nonblocking command in the socket code ,its not working.
So it would be great if anyone new a manual regarding recieving SPI and sending it over a socket.

Comment: First of, your code doesn't seem to have any SPI read. Second, you should test the stuff separately and then try to combine it. Your question isn't specific enough.

Comment: Yes, Its not reading because first i tried to send SPI data non stop.And in fact it only sends one SPI signal and stops.
I have tried to put non blocking commands nothing works.